# Prove $10^{n-1}\le a \lt 10^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{N}: \quad a = a_{n-1}\times10^{n-1} + a_{n-2}\times10^{n-2} + \dots + a_1\times10 + a_0 \\
a_{n-i} \in \{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9\}; \quad a_{n-1} \neq 0
$$

We say that $a$ has $n$ digits; it's important for proving something later but that's not what I'm having trouble with so it's not really relevant for this problem.

Although I've already proved $10^{n-1} \le a$, I'm struggling with the second part $a < 10^n$. I have all the elements for the proof but I'd like some help with putting them together:

1. $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}: a_{n-1} \lt 10 \Rightarrow
       a_{n-1}\times10^{n-1} \lt 10\times10^{n-1} \Rightarrow a_{n-1} \lt
       10^n$
2. $a_{n-1} \le 9 \Rightarrow a_{n-2}\times10^{n-2} + \dots + a_1\times10 + a_0$ would have to equal $10^{n-1}$ in order for
   $$
   \begin{align}
   a & = 9\times10^{n-1} + 10^{n-1} \\
   & = 10^{n-1}\times(9+1) \\
   & = 10^{n-1}\times10 \\
   & = 10^n 
   \end{align}
   $$
   but thanks to part 1, we already know $\sum_{k=2}^n a_{n-k}\times10^{n-k} \lt 10^{n-1}$, as we can recursively apply the same argument to each group of terms until we're just left with $n_0 \lt 10$.

I'm rather certain that a nice inductive proof can be constructed from this, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Uh... when I said I was having trouble proving $a\lt10^n$ and listed everything I thought I could use for the proof?

Comment: I am trying to prove that since it's impossible for each sum excluding the first term to equal the highest power of 10 in the whole sum, it will never be possible for the entire thing to equal $10^{n-1}$. By the way, I'd rather you explained that you have an issue with the title or phrasing instead of downvoting a carefully written/researched question that follows every guideline, because you aren't doing a very good job of welcoming beginners into the site.

Answer (score 1):

Given a decomposition of $a$ into digits as $a=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i10^i$ such that $a_{n-1}\ne0$ and each $a_i$ satisfies $0\le a_i<10$, we say that $a$ is an $n$-digit number (in base 10). Under these circumstances, we want to show:

> An $n$-digit number $a$ satisfies $10^{n-1}\le a<10^n$.

For the lower inequality, use the lower bounds $0\le a_i$ and $1\le a_{n-1}$ to get $$a=a_{n-1}10^{n-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a_i10^i\ge10^{n-1}+0.$$ For the upper bound, use the upper bound $a_i\le9$ to get
$$a=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i10^i\le\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}9\cdot10^i=9\cdot\frac{10^n-1}9<10^n$$ using the formula for the sum of a geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r^i=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Prove that $10^{n-1}$ is the smallest $n$ digit decimal number. Then prove that $10^{n}-1$ must be the largest $n$ digit decimal number, because $10^n$ is the smallest $n+1$ digit number.